# NHibernate SqlExeption was unhandled

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I study NHibernate and try to repeat the creating an application from the video course,
I created database, model, XML-file and then I wrote this code

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Driver;

namespace NHibernateDemo
{
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {
                x.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=NHibernateDemo; Integrated Security = SSPI";
                x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                x.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
            });
        cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var customers = session.CreateCriteria<Customer>()
                                   .List<Customer>();
            foreach (var customer in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", customer.FirstName, customer.LastName);
            }
            tx.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
}
```

but when I tried to debug it I got **SqlExeption was unhandled**

[image]

I suppose I need to add login and password in my code, but can someone explain me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You are using integrated securty, the user which is running your code has to have access:

```
Server=localhost; Database=NHibernateDemo; Integrated Security = SSPI
```

You can change your connection string to use a sql account or give the user access to your database.

Configure connectionstrings: [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Can you explain me how should I change my connection string?